# Subspace equipped with combinatorial structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, tensor-products

Given a vector space with tensor structure $V\otimes V\otimes V....\otimes V$, it is naturally (at least for us people doing many-body physics) to think that its subspaces are also equipped with some tenor structure.

Now could there be any possibility that vector space $V^{\otimes N^2}$ has a subspace equipped with a combinatorial structure instead of a tensor one, whose dimension is of order O(N!).

If there is, what shall be the proper mathematical structure between such two spaces? And how could that combinatorial structure naturally emerge from tensors?

Comment: The tensor space has dim. $n^{N^2}$, where $V$ has dim. $n$,  and you want the subspace to have dimension $N!$  ?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yep. Not necessarily $N!$, but at least at the same order ($log(dim)\sim NlogN$). Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "combinatorial structure"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It`s actually a question arise in physics, so sorry for the ambiguity in terminology. For example, consider a vector space spanned by all permutations of integer 1 to N over field C. Linear maps in this space are elements in group $S_N$ and also their linear combination. Formally, by 'combinatorial structure' I mean base vectors in this space can be labeled by some combinatorial objects, and maps in this space can be interpreted as some operation on these objects (like the permutation in example). Please let me know if I did not explain it clear enough or ill-defined anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $V$ be an $n$-dim. vector space. Consider the tensor space $V^{\otimes k}$ and let $V_i$ be an $i$-dim. subspace of $V$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Put $V_n=V$.

If $k\geq n$, then $V_n\otimes V_{n-1}\otimes \ldots\otimes V_1$ has dimension $n!$.

If $k<n$, then $V_n\otimes V_{n-1}\otimes \ldots\otimes V_{n-k+1}$ has dimension $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot \ldots\cdot (n-k+1)$.